# Windows attempting to run script with already manually deleted version of Python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.6

## How the problem came about

After looking for a deinstaller I ended up simply manually deleting the folder containing the version of Python (2.7.10) I wanted to delete on Windows. After the deletion I installed the newer version of Python I wanted to use (3.6). I started having some problems in my (at the time) text editor of choice PyCharm and with the default IDE Idle so I ended up deinstalling the newly installed version. Following that I attempted to reinstall the old version (2.7.10) but ended up installing (2.7.13) by accident.

## The actual problem

Now when I try to run a python script it attempts to run it with the no longer fully intact 2.7.10 version of Python, upon not finding it my computer then looks for the corresponding installer instead of using the currently installed version of Python as its default.

How do I clean up the old, manually deleted version of Python?

## Solution

In order to clean up a wrongly deinstalled program on Windows one can first look up what files and folders the program used outside of the folder that was manually deleted and delete those. Additionally one should check what values one should delete from the Windows registry using regedit.exe.

Also one doesn't necessarily need to delete old versions of Python in order to use new ones, most IDEs have ways to manage multiple versions of Python.

Comment: You can have multiple versions of python installed.  To uninstall, find the uninstaller of the start menu or run Control Panel, Programs, (exact name depends on Windows version, find python x.y on list, highlight, click uninstall.

Comment: I know but then its a head ache with all the programs and openers always needing the version specified and then always rewriting your programs and libraries if you need them for both. Thanks anyway

Comment: To be clear, in the statement "when i try to open idle it for some reason attempts to open the 2.7.10 version but realizes it doesnt exist and tries me to find the installer somewhere", the 'it' that attempts to open 2.7.10 (to run IDLE) is your Windows operating system not IDLE.  You would have the same problem trying to run any other python program  by the same method.  What Windows do you have and what method are you using to try to start Python to run a particular program?

Comment: The 'for some reason' is that you did not uninstall 2.7.10.  You merely crippled it by removing the directory.  This removal did not remove the registry entries that direct 'python' to the 2.7.10 directory, now removed.  Windows is not MSDOS, which had no registry.

Comment: I voted to close because this is not a programming question, but a Windows support question, which is explicitly off topic.  (Mouse over the Windows tag.)  Your question amounts to "How do I recover after screwing up my Windows Python installation?"  This would be on-topic on python-list (see https://mail.python.org//mailman/listinfo/python-list ).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so incase anybody has a similar issue the problem is there is a directory somewhere in windows with a bunch of shortcuts for python so just search with the windows searth thingy and then right click the corrupted idle go to directory and then simply delete